# Let $A = \{1, 2, n\}$. Show repeatedly taking the average of two elements from $A$ adding it to $A$, we can get all integers $\in \{1, 2, ... n\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{1, 2, n\}$. Show that by repeatedly taking the average of two elements from $A$ and adding it to $A$, we can obtain all integers between 1 and $n$, inclusive.

For example, with 1, 2, 7, we have 4 from 1 and 7, 3 from 2 and 4, 5 from 3 and 7, and 6 from 5 and 7. I just thought of this and I haven't found any solutions to problems of this sort.

Comment: Some sort of induction, based on the fact that $n-1= \dfrac {n+(n-2)}{2}$.

Comment: @ronno, that seems great!

Answer (score 6):

We will prove the statement while restricting to averages that are integers.

Let us work by induction on $n$, the statement being obvious for $n \le 3$. It suffices to show that $3$ is reachable from $\{1, 2, n\}$, since $(x + 1 + y + 1)/2 = (x + y)/2 + 1$, so a sequence of steps that reaches $k$ starting from $\{1, 2, n - 1\}$ will reach $k + 1$ starting from $\{2, 3, n\}$ and by induction this includes each $1 \le k \le n-1$, ie $2 \le k + 1 \le n$.

Now consider the sequence of numbers obtained by starting with $n$ and taking the average with either $1$ or $2$ depending on parity. That is, consider the sequence $f^k(n)$, where
$$f(m) = \begin{cases} \frac{1 + m}{2} & \text{ if $m$ is odd,}\\
\frac{2 + m}{2} & \text{ if $m$ is even.}\\\end{cases}$$
By induction on $k$, each $f^k(n)$ is reachable. Also note that for $m > 3$, $3 \le f(m) < m$. Therefore this sequence decreases to $3$, in particular must take the value $3$ at some step.